# FIXED Send POST request to server from client, Springboot

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send a post request, but springboot doesnt seem to recieve it.
My code:

Serverside reader

```
@RestController
public class MessageService {
    @PostMapping(path = "/online")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getResponse(){
        System.out.println("Post Recieved");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Client

```
private String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8090";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SpringApplication.run(Client.class, args);
    new StartupService().init();
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

StartupService/ POST Sender

```
public void init() throws IOException {
       String query = "Body";
        Client client = new Client();
        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
        URL mUrl = new URL(client.getUrl()+ "/online");
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
//query is body
        urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "POST");
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(query.length()));
        urlConn.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("Post Sent");
    }
```

I tried sending a POST request via Postman, which worked as expected and gave me the console output. But the POST from code isn't recieved from the server.

Comment: Content-Type: application/POST is not how to tell HttpClient send a post request. your code (if it works) is sending GET request

Comment: Yea thank you for the information it's fixed now, but definitely something to keep in mind for the future ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: I used a simpler method to send a POST:

```
javaClient userClient = new Client();
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create(userClient.getUrl()+ "/online"))
  .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(query))
  .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(
  request,
  HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()
);

System.out.println(response.body());

System.out.println("Post Sent");
```